# fixing win10 to use with pro audio and even normal users

Tags: windows-10

I recall long lists of fixes needed on  winxp and win7 ,  plus some changes needed for win 8 so that serious audio users could use their PCs without fear of windoze screwing us over by claiming they were 'helping' us  by  'fixing' something totally irrelevant to real life.

So is there a list anywhere of all the changes that are needed so that we can use our win10 devices to do serious audio work?

Is there another list of changes needed so vanilla users can avoid getting screwed over by windoze 'help' like win8 did to me a couple of times.  EG it decided to save 'power' while making my usbs all UNusable.

Is there anything users can  to make win10 useful for real work and not just as a social media toy?  Win10 screwed my usb memory stick so it would not work on other devices anymore, where it had worked before I tried to use it to move data to win 10.

Comment: This is a bit of a rant.  Windows 10 Pro does not break USB Keys. I make keys on Windows 10 and move the keys to other devices and use them successfully.  Power management functions can be easily tamed. You need to learn what is going on here. Given some learning on your part, what is it you cannot do?

Comment: sorry but my win10 destroyed my usb memory stick for use elsewhere.  i moved data from an xp to the win10 and after that it would not work on any other device but the win ten.  so RANT?+==TRUTH!!.  and if you have not used windoze for serious audio work then you have no idea of all the fixes needed on earlier versions to be sure it was reliable

Comment: I think there ar third party apps for audio work. My more simple needs are met by windows. I have an XP virtual machine (SMBv1 only) and move data from Windows 10 to XP and back again on USB Key so I am not having those issues. I suggest a third party app for more heavy duty audio work.

Comment: @John -  The issue is the opsys.   I have great programs to handle the audio if I can be sure the PC does not cause noise problems or the opsys screws me over somehow.  there used to be long lists of changes to make in the settings to run audio better.  EG  turn off antivirus (after disconnecting from the internet) delete all the crapware that phones home.

Comment: I believe there may have been a question here recently showing a humongously long list of needless stuff someone had deleted or turned off.  I dont know if I need all that so I asked about an audio specific list.  I have seen such lists for xp and 7 possibly even 8.1.  But so far not for win10.   Maybe win10 is too far gone to be tweaked to be useful for real work reliably.